# PHP web-app cripples entire website

Tags: php, sleep, execution

I have a web-app that fetches the content of various sources to test for the existence of a certain keyword in that text.

The problem is is that when that program runs the entire website becomes unresponsive.

I have tried adding sleep(1); everywhere so it get's some break time, but the only thing that does is make the execution longer and thusly keep my website unresponsive for a longer period.

Is there another solution to prevent one program to halt the entire website or affect the entire website?

Here's the code example(please don't mind the use of mysql instead of mysqli... The website was handed to me as is, and for the moment it's too much work to revamp the website to mysqli)

```
function updatethestuff()
        {
        $count = 0;
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', '1');
        $this->write_file(FCPATH . '/pagemodules/rssfeedlog.txt','Begin met het verwerken van alle rssfeeds'."\n",'w');
        $feeds = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM rsscanner.feeds where `url` not like 'disabled' order by `id` asc");
        foreach($feeds->result() as $feed)
            {

            if(!isset($this->rssparser))
                {
                $this->load->library('RSSParser', array('url' => $feed->url, 'life' => 2));
                }
            else
                {
                $this->rssparser->reinit(array('url' => $feed->url, 'life' => 2));
                }
            $this->write_file(FCPATH.'/pagemodules/rssfeedlog.txt','Begin met parsen van resultaten van ' . $feed->naam . "\n");
            $data = $this->rssparser->getFeed(20);
            foreach ($data as $item) 
                {
                $innerHTML='';
                $link = mysql_real_escape_string($item['link']);
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT feed_id from rsscanner.rsscontent where url='$link' limit 0,1");
                $this->write_file(FCPATH . '/pagemodules/rssfeedlog.txt',$feed->naam . ': Aantal keren dat ' . $link . ' al voorkomt is ' . $query->num_rows() . "\n");
                sleep(1);
                if($query->num_rows() == 0)
                    {                   
                    $dom = new DOMDocument();
                    $dom->validateOnParse = false;
                    $html = get_data($item['link']);
                    $dom->loadHTML($html);
                    $this->write_file(FCPATH . '/pagemodules/rssfeedlog.txt',$feed->naam . ': HTML data geladen' . "\n");
                    sleep(1);
                    if(isset($feed->contentdiv))
                        {
                        $x = $dom->getElementById($feed->contentdiv);
                        $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
                        $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($x, true)); 
                        $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 
                        $this->write_file(FCPATH . '/pagemodules/rssfeedlog.txt',$feed->naam . ': Informatie uit de contentdiv("' . $feed->contentdiv . '") geladen'. "\n");
                        sleep(1);
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        $finder = new DomXPath($dom);
                        $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' {$feed->containerclass} ')]");
                        $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
                         foreach ($nodes as $node) 
                            {
                            $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($node,true));
                            }
                        $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 
                        $this->write_file(FCPATH . '/pagemodules/rssfeedlog.txt',$feed->naam . ': Informatie uit de content class("' . $feed->containerclass . '") geladen' . "\n");
                        sleep(1);
                        }
                    unset($dom);
                    unset($tmp_dom);
                    $innerHTML = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($innerHTML));
                    $this->write_file(FCPATH . '/pagemodules/rssfeedlog.txt',$feed->naam . ': html veilig gemaakt voor database'. "\n");
                    sleep(1);
                    $q=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `rsscanner`.`zoekwoorden` union select * from `rsscanner`.`zoekwoord_synoniem`");

                    $found = false;
                    $keywordsstring = "";
                    $lowerhtml = strtolower($innerHTML);
                    $this->write_file(FCPATH . '/pagemodules/rssfeedlog.txt',$feed->naam . ': Begin met zoekwoord vergelijking'. "\n");
                    sleep(1);
                    foreach($q->result() as $r)
                        {
                        if(strpos($lowerhtml,strtolower($r->zoekwoord)) !== false)
                            {
                            $found = true;
                            $keywordsstring = "$keywordsstring ".$r->zoekwoord;
                            $this->write_file(FCPATH . '/pagemodules/rssfeedlog.txt',$feed->naam . ': - Match met zoekwoord: ' . $r->zoekwoord . "\n");
                            sleep(1);
                            }

                        }
                    if($found)
                        {

                        $keywordsstring = mysql_real_escape_string($keywordsstring);
                        $title = mysql_real_escape_string($item['title']);
                        $desc = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($item['description']));
                        $date = mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($item['pubDate'])));
                        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO rsscanner.rsscontent (feed_id,title,description,published,url,content,keywords_found) 
                                                                    VALUES ('{$feed->id}','$title','$desc','$date','$link','$innerHTML','$keywordsstring')");
                        $this->write_file(FCPATH . '/pagemodules/rssfeedlog.txt',$feed->naam . ': Opslaan in database als geldig zoekresultaat' . "\n");

                        }
                    else
                        {

                        $keywordsstring = mysql_real_escape_string($keywordsstring);
                        $title = mysql_real_escape_string($item['title']);
                        $desc = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($item['description']));
                        $date = mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($item['pubDate'])));
                        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO rsscanner.rsscontent (feed_id,title,description,published,url,content,keywords_found) 
                                                                    VALUES ('{$feed->id}','$title','$desc','1983-05-10 09:10:53','$link','$innerHTML','NO MATCH')");
                        $this->write_file(FCPATH . '/pagemodules/rssfeedlog.txt',$feed->naam . ': markeren in database als een no match' . "\n");
                        }
                    sleep(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        echo "done";
        }
```

Comment: Is the webserver running on your computer?

Comment: @sirko I am using ajax to access the call. It's the app that is called by ajax that causes the trouble by it's heavy execution.
The webserver is a professional webserver. I find it ridicilous that an entire website becomes unresponsive because of one ap.

Comment: If you really need to check these things, you either need to improve the code that is being used to check the existence of keywords, or ramp up the memory in your server to cope.  Posting the actual code/ technique being used might be a better approach.

Comment: Are you using a session in that _web app_? And as @Coulton said, posting some code would help ;)

Comment: Have you run the database queries your script is running directly on the MySQL server to see how long they each take?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM rsscanner.feeds where url not like 'disabled' order by id asc` - I don't like the look of that; a separate `disabled` flag in the DB would be better. Also, is `url` indexed?

Comment: yes, url is indexed. I need to optimise it at some stage but I'm still using this as work in progress.
First I need it not to hang the app.
This query only takes 0.00045 seconds to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be an option to put this task as a background process?

For example use Gearman

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.gearman.php